# Xamarin iOS Unwind Segue or DismissViewController programmatically and pass back data

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, storyboard, segue

I have created a segue in my storyboard.  It is a modal segue and I gave it an identifier of LoginSegue.

In my controller, I do:

```
PerformSegue("LoginSegue", this);
```

All is well.  New controller comes up as expected.

To return to the calling view, I can use an unwind segue by wiring a button to the unwind segue in the calling controller.  This works fine.

Or I can call (from code):

```
DismissViewController(true, null);
```

The thing is that I want to pass back some data.

The `ParentViewController` is null.

I do need to do some validation before I return to the calling view, so doing the auto unwind from a button is not an option.

```
   [Action("UnwindToCaller:")]
   public void UnwindToCaller(UIStoryboardSegue seque)
   {
       var loginViewController = (LoginViewController)seque.SourceViewController;
       var data = loginViewController.getData();
       Console.WriteLine("Unwind to Caller Here.");
   }
```

I also cannot seem to find a way to give the unwind segue a storyboard Id.

If I could perform the unwind segue from code everything would be good, or if I could pass some data back with the DismissViewController that would be good too.

Again, this seems like a pretty common thing to do.

Comment: If you click on the segue in the scene list on the left side of the window, you can then use the attributes inspector to give it an identifier. You can use prepareForSegue to send data back to the initial controller with an unwind, just like you do for a forward segue.

Comment: Forgot to mention.  I am using Visual Studio.  I do not see a "Scene list".  I can see all my push segues in the storyboard and in the document outline (and give them identifiers), just not the unwind segue.

Comment: Is the "LoginSegue" a modal segue? If that is the case, try checking the value of the "PresentingViewController" property on the Login controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found a solution.  Hope this helps others.

So in my calling view controller, when I PrepareForSegue, I pass a reference to the calling view controller.  Then I have a method that is called from the modal view.

Here is the Xamarin reference: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/storyboard/storyboard_a_tableview/

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
   {
       if (segue.Identifier == "LoginSegue")
       {
           var destCtrl = segue.DestinationViewController as LoginViewController;
           if (destCtrl != null)
           {
               // pass in a reference to THIS view controller.
               destCtrl.SetData(this);
           }
       }
       base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);
   }
```

Also in the Calling View Controller

```
   public void LoggedIn (string someFlag)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Logged in with : " + someFlag);
       DismissViewController(true, null);
   }
```

And the LoginViewController

```
public void SetData (CallingViewController callingCtrl)
    {
        calllingViewController = callingCtrl;
    }
```

Then when I am ready to return.

```
callingViewController.LoggedIn("the flag");
```